# how to show these results in one line in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

currently i have these three table, the structures are very similar

```
table1:id1 name1
table2:id2 name2
table3:id3 name3
```

my desired results will be

```
name1  name2   name3
value1 value2  value3
```

I try to use union, the sql is:

```
select name1 from table1 where id1 = '1' 
union select name2 from table2 where id2 = '2' 
union select name3 from table3 where id3 = '3'
```

but the result turns out to be:

```
name1     
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: Do you want to select _exactly_ from `id1=1` and `id2=2` and `id3=3`, or there is some rule to combine?

Comment: the 1,2,3 will be parameters derived from the user input

Comment: did ur problem not solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  (select name1 from table1 where id1 = '1'),
  (select name2 from table2 where id2 = '2'),
  (select name3 from table3 where id3 = '3')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name1,name2,name3 from table1,table2,table3
where table1.id1=1 and table2.id2=2 and table3.id3=3;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f332f/4)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871576/performance-subquery-or-joining  .. Worth fine for a refernce.